# cannot find package "k8s.io/metrics/pkg/client/clientset/versioned" in any of:Vendor , GOROOT , GOPATH

Tags: go, kubernetes, makefile, package, vendor

I am trying to create i scheduler so after writing the code and creating deployment i use a make file to build and use vendor also but when i use my first code which use the same imports as the code in github reposetory it works but when i add to it and use k8s.io/metrics/pkg/client/clientset/versioned as import it give me an error:

```
    cmd/scheduler/main.go:24:5: cannot find package "k8s.io/metrics/pkg/client/clientset/versioned" in any of:
    /go/src/github.com/username/scheduler/vendor/k8s.io/metrics/pkg/client/clientset/versioned (vendor tree)
    /usr/local/go/src/k8s.io/metrics/pkg/client/clientset/versioned (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/k8s.io/metrics/pkg/client/clientset/versioned (from $GOPATH)
```

makefile:

```
    SHELL = /bin/bash
    OS = $(shell uname -s)
    PACKAGE = github.com/username/scheduler
    BINARY_NAME = scheduler
    IMAGE = name
    TAG = tagsvalue
    
    BUILD_DIR ?= build
    BUILD_PACKAGE = ${PACKAGE}/cmd/scheduler
    DEP_VERSION = 0.5.0
    GOLANG_VERSION = 1.11

    .PHONY: clean
    clean: ## Clean the working area and the project
           rm -rf bin/ ${BUILD_DIR}/ vendor/
           rm -rf ${BINARY_NAME}

    bin/dep: bin/dep-${DEP_VERSION}
           @ln -sf dep-${DEP_VERSION} bin/dep
   bin/dep-${DEP_VERSION}:
            @mkdir -p bin
            curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh |   INSTALL_DIRECTORY=bin DEP_RELEASE_TAG=v${DEP_VERSION} sh
            @mv bin/dep $@

    .PHONY: vendor
    vendor: bin/dep ## Install dependencies
           bin/dep ensure -v -vendor-only

    .PHONY: build
    build: ## Build a binary
            go build ${BUILD_PACKAGE}
```

please help i know that the question is not to clear but i am a new to golang so any information will help. thank you

Comment: erm... `dep` has been deprecated years ago. You're using go version 1.11, why bother with a makefile and external tools for dependency management? Just use `go mod` instead. Building the binary when using `go mod` is as easy as `go build` or `go install`, it checks and fetches dependencies for you. Maintenance is done through `go mod {download,install,tidy,...}` (`go help mod` for details)

Comment: i am new to this i try to follow some project similar to what i want . so what you saying that i eliminate that dep part in the makefile ? could you please explain what i should do i am just whanting to run the code without error

Comment: You need to remove `dep` which no longer works, update to a supported Go version, and use modules for dependency management. The basics are covered in [How to Write Go Code](https://go.dev/doc/code)

Comment: OK that's clear, thanks for the help. i will try my best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, seeing as you want to know how to use go modules, I'll write a brief summary. The full documentation is [here](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules), on the go.dev site. It's easy to find, and walks you through the entire process beginning to end.

---

I have been using go as my main language since go 1.4. Since the introductions of go modules, I can honestly say that I rarely, if ever, need a Makefile. To use modules is fantastically easy:

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir new_project
& cd new_project
# initialise module
$ go mod init github.com/user/new_project
$ ls
go.mod
$ cat go.mod
module github.com/user/new_project

go 1.19
# the version in the mod file will reflect the version of go you have installed locally
```

Now to add dependencies:

```
$ go get github.com/jinzhu/copier
# check:
$ ls
go.mod    go.sum
$ cat go.mod
module github.com/user/new_project

go 1.19

require github.com/jinzhu/copier v0.3.5 // indirect
```

The dependency was added, and a `go.sum` file is created. This acts as a lock file for your dependencies. It's basically the commit hash of the exact version used in your project.

You can specify a specific version (saw we want version v0.3.2 instead of 0.3.5), you can just use the command:

```
$ go get github.com/jinzhu/copier@v0.3.2
```

Or you can manually add dependencies to your mod file in your editor:

```
module github.com/user/new_project

go 1.19

require (
   github.com/jinzhu/copier v0.3.2
   github.com/foo/bar
)
```

And so on. Check the docs for things like `replace` and `require_test`, and what they do.

Now you can just compile your code:

```
$ go build .
```

Any dependencies that you haven't downloaded yet will be automatically checked and updated/downloaded for you. If you want to download the dependencies manually, you can:

```
$ go mod download
```

If you want to remove dependencies that are no longer in use (ie clean up the  go.sum file):

```
$ go mod tidy
```

There's nothing more to it, really.

Comment: THAT'S GREAT !!!! thank you for the respond it's clear and help me a lot

Comment: just a litle thing what the GOROOT and GOPATH should be ? because when running go build i get so many error that say package <package_name> in not in GOROOT

Comment: With modules, the `GOPATH` can be anything. The project doesn't have to be in the `GOPATH`, but `go mod` will download the dependencies in `$GOPATH/mod`, make sure to set it to somewhere you have write permission to (e.g. `$HOME/go`). you needn't change `GOROOT`, that's the path go falls back to for standard lib imports

Comment: @ghost44: NP. If this answer solved your question, then please consider up-voting and/or marking it as the accepted answer

Comment: ok i know that now this is somthing else, but i am trying to execute a shell command (kubectl ) in go code but am facing error : exec: "kubectl": executable file not found in $PATH: i try to ak a question but stackoverflow won't let me